# Why this works, when it shouldnt ? passing by reference

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2, pass-by-reference

Here is standard `Yii2` `SearchModel` `search` action

```
public function search($params, $cond)
{
    $query = Service::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    $query->where(['param' => $value]); //why this modified after it passed to provider?

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Why theres `$query` is modified AFTER is passed as parameter to `ActiveDataProvider` and it works ? How array with params keeping reference to `$query` ?

Comment: [passing by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) is 'declared' in the function declaration, not when calling the function (=at runtime).

Comment: Objects are always references, except if you clone it explicitly

Comment: But inside anonymous parameter, how it is possible ?

Comment: `$query` is passed in an array. So the prototype of `ActiveDataProvider` will have a parameter defined as an array

Comment: this `public function __construct($config = [])` is the declaration of the BaseObject, which `ActiveDataProvider` inherites from. Just for info (because I was searching for it).

Comment: Thanks, I did search whole extend chain and not found BaseObject, only Object without __construct

Answer (score 5):

`ActiveQuery` is mutable object, and in PHP objects are always passed by reference. In your case reference to `$query` is assigned to `$dataProvider->query`, so `$query` and `$dataProvider->query` points to the same object. Any modification of `$query` will be also reflected on `$dataProvider->query`.

You may read more about this in [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php).